# Socket.io wrong data being sent to socket (possible ID collisions)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

We are currently experiencing an issue with our web application where the wrong data is being sent to a socket. Based on what we are seeing, it appears there might be socketID collisions because of our multiple server setup but we have not been able to confirm yet.

**The behavior**

Users that are joined to 1 room will start receiving messages from another room (that they have not been joined to) at random. When they refresh, they are back to getting the messages that they were supposed to be getting.

**Our configuration**

```
var express = require('express')();
var api = require('http').createServer(express);

/*
 * Configure socket.io.
 */
var socketio = require('socket.io')(api, {
  serveClient: true,
  transports: ['websocket']
});
var redis = require('redis').createClient;
var adapter = require('socket.io-redis');
var pub = redis(appModules.config.redis.clients.socketio.port, appModules.config.redis.clients.socketio.host, {
  return_buffers: true,
  auth_pass: appModules.config.redis.password
});
var sub = redis(appModules.config.redis.clients.socketio.port, appModules.config.redis.clients.socketio.host, {
  return_buffers: true,
  auth_pass: appModules.config.redis.password
});
socketio.adapter(adapter({
  host: appModules.config.redis.clients.socketio.host,
  port: appModules.config.redis.clients.socketio.port,
  pubClient: pub,
  subClient: sub
}));
socketio.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('connection-event', 'socket connection successful for socket: ' + socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    require('../../main_socket/v1/disconnect')(this);
  });
  socket.on('reconnect', function() {
    require('../../main_socket/v1/reconnect')(this);
  });
  socket.on('client-event', function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    appModules.shared.session.decryptToken(data.token)
      .then(function(jwt) {
        appModules.services.redis.clients.user_sessions.hgetallAsync(jwt.decodedToken.email)
          .then(function(session) {
            data.session = session;
            require('../../main_socket/' + data.apiVersion + '/' + data.context + '/' + data.action)(data, socket);
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            logger.error(err);
          });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        logger.error(err);
      });
  });
});
```

**Assumption**

Since refreshing seems to fix the issue for a specific user, we assume it is a socketID collision since they will get a new one on refresh.

**Additional Notes**

We are hosting our app on Heroku and followed their instructions for session affinity (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity) but this did not seem to make any impact on the issue.